# Android viewflipper animation lag

Tags: android, animation, transition, viewflipper, lag

I have some basic animations that work like a charm when they are used for transitions between the activities.

The problem is that when I use them on my viewflipper I see a very noticeable lag.
Here is a code snippet from my activity:

```
 private void initUI(){
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    flipViewMain = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.flip_view_profile_main, null);
    flipListHolder = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.flip_view_profile_list, null);
    flipDescriptionHolder  =  layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.flip_view_profile_description, null);

    profileFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.profile_flipper);

    profileFlipper.addView(flipViewMain);
    profileFlipper.addView(flipListHolder);
    profileFlipper.addView(flipDescriptionHolder);

    flipInNextAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.push_left_in);
    flipOutNextAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.push_left_out);
    flipInPreviousAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.push_right_in);
    flipOutPreviousAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.push_right_out);
 }

  private void handleFlip(int position){
    if(position<currentPosition){
        profileFlipper.setInAnimation(flipInPreviousAnimation);
        profileFlipper.setOutAnimation(flipOutPreviousAnimation);
    } else if(position>currentPosition){
        profileFlipper.setInAnimation(flipInNextAnimation);
        profileFlipper.setOutAnimation(flipOutNextAnimation);
    }
    currentPosition = position;

    profileFlipper.setDisplayedChild(position);
}
```

All animation are like this one:

```
<translate android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="0" android:duration="300"/>
<alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="300" />

 </set>
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I get rid of this lag? I thought that maybe I would better use a ViewPager but it seems like it is not very flexible in terms of animation modifications. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the problem was not caused by the ViewFlipper. I noticed the animation lag only when debugging on my Galaxy Nexus device. I found out [here](http://www.dkeesto.com/?p=198) that:

> The Galaxy Nexus is 1280 x 720 for a total of 921K pixels on screen.
>   So basically, the GPU on the Galaxy Nexus has to draw 2.4 times as
>   many pixels per frame as the it does on the Infuse or S II. The potential frame rate can be expected to be roughly 2.4 times worse on the Galaxy Nexus as it can on the Infuse or Galaxy S II.

That's the reason for my animation problem. Solved it by enabling hardware acceleration:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED);
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.content);

    initUI();

}
```